# Given year only, find last day of February

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a sql server function that when given the year only as a string returns the last day of February or returns whether or not if that year is a leap year

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4)
SET @Year = '2013'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,@Year+'0301')
```

Comment: The leap part is missing. Maybe: `SELECT LastDay = DAY(d.Day)
     , IsLeap = CASE WHEN DAY(d.Day) > 28 
                Then 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
FROM (SELECT Day=DATEADD(DAY,-1,@Year+'0301'))d`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, the question said that it should return the last day of february **or** if it's a leap year. I chose the first

Answer (score 5):

Check if can divisible by 4 or 100 or 400.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

```
select case when
    (
        (@year % 4 = 0) and (@year % 100 != 0) or
        (@year % 400 = 0)
    ) then 'LEAP' else 'USUAL' end
;
```

Comment: can you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: This calculates leap year. When a year is divisible by 4, it's a leap year, unless it is also divisible by 100. The exception being when it is also divisible by 400. So when that case evaluation returns true, we know it's a leap year; otherwise it's normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with .....and it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LastDayOfFeb] (@YEAR INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      RETURN 
        (SELECT CASE datepart(mm, dateadd(dd, 1, cast((cast(@year as varchar(4)) + '0228') as datetime)))
                  WHEN 2 THEN '0229' + Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(8)) 
                  ELSE '0228' + Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(8)) 
                END) 
  END
```